# Why does this failed validation event fire after I have made the value valid?

Tags: jquery

I run this code onclick of a submit button:

```
if ($("#zipcode").val().length < 5) {
    $("#users_search").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#please-zipcode").modal();
    });
}
```

The expected result is that ONLY when the field zipcode has fewer than than 5 characters should the modal be opened.

Current behavior: When the form with an empty zipcode field is submitted, it opens the modal (as expected). Then, after closing the modal, no matter what value I enter in the zipcode field (valid or not), it opens the modal (which shouldn't happen if the value is greater than five characters). Where am I wrong? Please help.

Comment: More code required or create a fiddle

Comment: u mean rendered html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't want to bind the submit handler within another event. Remove it from any event bound to the button and try this:

```
$("#users_search").submit(function (e) {
   if ($("#zipcode").val().length < 5) {
        e.preventDefault();
         $("#please-zipcode").modal();
   }else{
      /* unless using ajax form would submit using browser default*/
      /* if want ajax submit, do it here and move  e.preventDefault(); out of "if"*/
   }
});
```